Parallelization Optimization
I want to parallelize the shuffling and analyzing of decks.
I tried many synchronization libraries to no avail. What should I do to increase efficiency?
I have already tried finding other parallelization libraries, but found nothing useful.
import concurrent.futures
from random import shuffle

from ddstable import ddstable

solve = ddstable.get_ddstable

...

def sort(cards):
    return [[
        _[0] for _ in sorted(filter(lambda x: x[1] == suit, cards),
                             key=lambda x: 'AKQJT98765432'.index(x[0]))
    ] for suit in 'SHDC']

def prettysolve(cards):
    s = []
    all = solve(bytes(PBN(cards), 'utf-8'))
    s.append("  {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2} {:>2}".format("S", "H", "D", "C", "NT"))
    for each in all:
        x = ''
        x += "{:>1}".format(each)
        for suit in ddstable.dcardSuit:
            trick = all[each][suit]
            x += " {:2}".format(trick - 6)
        s.append(x)
    return '\n'.join(s)

def shuffle_and_solve(_):
    cards = [(i, j) for i in '23456789TJQKA' for j in 'CDHS']
    shuffle(cards)
    result = prettysolve(cards)
    return cards, result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_decks = 16

    # Using concurrent.futures for parallel processing
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(shuffle_and_solve, _) for _ in range(num_decks)]
        outputs = [future.result() for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]

    sets, results = zip(*outputs)

    with open('decks.txt', 'w') as f:
        ...



@9769953 how do I confirm that on a Mac?

and yes, ddstable is the double dummy analyzer in bridge, presumably taking up a lot of time.

@9769953 its very slow, and i want it to be much faster. Currently it analyzes 4 decks every second, but I want something closer to 100.

Additionally, I'm using repl.it, so that might be relevant as well. I couldn't install ddstable on my local machine.

Comparison: it takes 10 seconds to analyze 16 decks, and 1.4 seconds to analyze 4.

@9769953 Is there some way I can automate the poccess?

What do you mean @9769953?

I guess "I want to parallelize" is for performance. So if the problem is to improve performance the first step is to analyze where the time is spent. Probably the solve() and the double for O(n^2). If the problem is the solve, the only way is to parallelize more. Consider that some library cannot perform well in multithreading. Have you tried something multiprocess like celery or ray? Ray can be tested easily.
